# Need a functions that adds (adm)/(mod) if current user is admin/moderator right after their username

Tags: functions

When a moderator/admin leaves a comment I want them to stand out and not be like any other comment. I have this piece of code so far but I dont think will do any good

```
<?php $current_user_is_a_mod = current_user_can( 'edit_others_posts' );if ( $current_user_is_a_mod ) echo '(mod)'; ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can ask for roles with `current_user_can()` too:

```
current_user_can( 'administrator' )
```

or

```
current_user_can( 'editor' )
```

There is no built-in role `moderator`.

Comment: I use s2mem and it creates that role.

Comment: The codex might be plain wrong and/or outdated - but in case it's not: The codex article on [`current_user_can`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/current_user_can) suggest to not use it for checking non-core roles. Hence, `in_array( 'moderator', $current_user->roles )` might be the better route to take.